# adding delay between operations(obj c)

Tags: objective-c, delay

I am relatively new to obj c so for my school work I need to add delay between the execution of three lines in a(same) function. Is there is any favorable options to do this?

```
line 1: [executing first operation];

line 2: Delay  /* I need to introduce delay here */

line 3: [executing second operation];

line 4: Delay  /* I need to introduce delay here again */

line 5: [executing second operation];
```

thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read up on Grand Central Dispatch.

Comment: @rmaddy is it possible for you to give me an example on gcd?

Comment: Search. You'll find plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0):

so the solution i found is:

```
[operation 1]
    double delayInSeconds = 9.3;
    dispatch_time_t popTime2 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [operation 2];

double delayInSeconds2 = 9.3;
dispatch_time_t popTime2 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds2 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime2, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
   [operation 3];

 });

 });
```

is this the correct way to do it?
and if it is,is there anyway that i would not need to nest operation 3 in operation 2's Delay

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the goal by NSRunLoop method - (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(nullable id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;

```
[executing first operation];
[self performSelector:@selector(2nd_Operation) withObject:nil 
 afterDelay:1st_Delay_In_Seconds];
[self performSelector:@selector(3rd_Operation) withObject:nil 
 afterDelay:2nd_Delay_In_Seconds];
```

Be aware that if you put the above codes in one method, both delay time start at almost the same time. If you want to say call 2nd_operation after 0.5s delay then  call 3rd_operation after another 0.5s delay, then 2nd_Delay_Time should be 0.5s+2nd_operation executing time+0.5s. If you need accurate delay for  whatever reason, I suggest put the last line in complete block of 2nd_operation.